# Hover issue on webkit browsers

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with fixing an issue with CSS hover on webkit browsers. The code is somewhat like this..

```css
#working .info{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 19px;
    height: 21px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
}
#working .info:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

#working .info:hover + .infoTip, {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 100;
}
```

The issue is only with webkit browsers.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML you are using for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "somewhat like this"? Is this the code you are using or not? Are the errors pointed out in @Razz's answer in your live code? Can you reproduce the issue in a demo?

Comment: Here is the File that I am working on, This is the first time ever I am running into such a problem. http://uniquestsolutions.com/alton/working/  The additional classes and id's you see are only because this website was already done by some one else and I have been asked to do one similar page. I have tried to reuse as many classes as possible but the hover seems to break only on webkit browsers... Try the hover over the plus signs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a comma in the end of `.infoTip` that probably ruining it, and opacity: 100 isnt right, try this instead.

```
#working .info:hover + .infoTip {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Edit after OPs update:

Chrome somehow bugs out when rendering opacity: 0 again. But it will work if you use display: none; instead.

```
.infoTip{
  display: none;
}

#working .info:hover + .infoTip{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is impossible to figure out what causing your problem without seeing your html.

Comment: Here is the File that I am working on, This is the first time ever I am running into such a problem. uniquestsolutions.com/alton/working The additional classes and id's you see are only because this website was already done by some one else and I have been asked to do one similar page. I have tried to reuse as many classes as possible but the hover seems to break only on webkit browsers... Try the hover over the plus signs

Comment: It looks like chrome is having troubles rendering opacity: 0. when i scroll down past the popup it dissapears. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Try This CsS

```
enter code here
    #working .info{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 19px;
    height: 21px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
#working .info:hover
{
    opacity: 1;
}

#working .info:hover + .infoTip, {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what changes you did, and why?